# Affect the sum of an Autofilled column to a variable in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Suppose I have, in Excel, a vector of 10 rows (cells A1 to A10) containing letters and I want to extract the number of occurrences of the letter "X".

This is a minimal working example that shows the solution I propose to solve the problem:

```vba
Sub Macro1()

    Range("B1").Activate 
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]=""X"",1,0)"
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B1:B10"), Type:=xlFillDefault

    Range("B11").Activate
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-10]C:R[-1]C)"

End Sub
```

Basically, I use a condition where the result, put in cell Bi, is 1 if the content of cell Ai is "X" or 0 otherwise. I do an autofill to test all the rows i=1 to 10, then I sum up the result in the end.

What I want is for the autofill result not to appear, i.e. I want to affect the autofill result to a variable for e.g., that does not show on the sheet, then sum the content of all the cells (resulted from the autofill) and only show the final result (the sum).

Is there a way to do this? All suggestions are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Why not use COUNTIF(): `=COUNTIF(A1:A10,"X")`?

Comment: @ScottCraner I'm a novice to VBA, I didn't know about this function. Furthermore, this is a simplified version of my real problem.

Comment: @ScottCraner What I really want is not to count the number of occurrences of "X". Instead, suppose you have another column (B for e.g) that contains, let's say, prices (relative to content of column A: content of cell A1 has a price B1...), what I want is to extract the total cost of element "X".

Comment: That is a different question:  Look into SUMIF().  Very similar to COUNTIF()

Comment: @ScottCraner In this case, all I have to do is to adapt the condition such that it takes the price in column B if in column A there is "X" or put 0 instead.

Comment: `=SUMIF(A:A,"X",B:B)`

Comment: @ScottCraner Okay. Seems to do what I want. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use COUNTIF(): `=COUNTIF(A1:A10,"X")`?

But as far as your code:

```
Sub Macro1()        

    Range("B11").FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(R[-10]C[-1]:R[-1]C[-1],""X"")"

End Sub
```